# How to remove Grand Total columns from Matrix Report in salesforce?

Tags: reporting, matrix

I have a Matrix Report and i want to remove the Grand Total Column and row in the table.Below is the Image of the report.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find this article that looks to show an option in Lightning to remove Grand Totals and Subtotals.  I will warn you that once a report is edited in Lightning, it is no longer available in Salesforce Classic.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000240316&language=en_US